# 301 Redirect for All Subdirectories

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am changing domain names for a WordPress site and want to set up a structure like so:

If a user accesses **olddomain.com/page**, he will be re-directed to **newdomain.com/page**, etc. In other words, only the pre-slash part of the domain would change. I want to do this for all pages under the old domain.

So far, I have only been able to get **olddomain.com** to re-direct to **newdomain.com**, but not any of the sub-directories (for example, **olddomain.com/page** does not re-direct to **newdomain.com/page**). Here is my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN GD-SSL
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(.+)$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^newdomain\.com$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=300"
</IfModule>
# END GD-SSL


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must put all of the redirect rules **before** your routing rules. The wordpress rules route *everything* to `index.php`, including anything you intend to redirect. So the redirects must happen before any sort of internal routing happens.

Simply put your redirect rule before the wordpress rules:

```
# BEGIN GD-SSL
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(.+)$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^newdomain\.com$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=300"
</IfModule>
# END GD-SSL

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]    

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your .htaccess to the below code on the old domain:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.olddomain.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

This will redirect the entire website on a page by page basis.

Comment: Why "!^www" in front of olddomain.com? The old domain does not have "www" in it.

Comment: @John Roberts - What we are saying here is with or without the www. That way if someone types in the olddomain.com with the www.olddomain.com it will still go to the correct place.